# cannot access onActivityResult() method in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult, filepicker

I am a beginner in `Android`.

I am going to make image picker from camera and file explorer.

I found out example code from google search.

But after capture, it don't call `onActivityResult()` Method.

So I cannot handle the capture result.

note: I am working on `Fragment`.

```
public void selectImage(){
final String [] items = new String [] {"Take Photo", "Choose Photo"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add/Change Photo");
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File file        = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    try {
                        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        } );
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

        // TODO Fix no activity available
        if (resultCode != getActivity().RESULT_OK)
            return;
        Bitmap bitmap   = null;
        String path     = "";
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); // From Gallery

            if (path == null)
                path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); // From File Manager

            if (path != null)
                bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }
        else {
            path    = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
            bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }

        imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

calling `getActivity().startActivityForResult()` will result a call to **onActivityResult()** on the **Activity** hosting the Fragment and not the **onActivityResult()** of the **Fragment** it self.

If you want a call to **onActivityResult()** in the *Fragment itself* call

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

and if you want to handle it it the Activity you need to call:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),  PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

Also you might want to reorganize your onActivityResult()  as

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // TODO Fix no activity available
        if (resultCode != getActivity().RESULT_OK)
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String path = "";
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); // From Gallery

            if (path == null)
                path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); // From File Manager

            if (path != null)
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        } else {
            path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }

        imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment code you need to call the activity from the fragment. Instead of:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

you need to call the following, as your code is inside a nested class.

```
YOUR_FRAGMENT.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

without `getActivity`.

Comment: Thanks for your time.
But I tried to access without getActivity(), but I cannot .
Any other idear?

Comment: Why can't you do that?

Comment: check if you get the cursor in the onActivityResult() method of the parent activity of this fragment

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed this issue.
I used tab host e.g MainActivity - TabActivity - Fragment
I access startActivityForResult()
So I resolved getAcvtivity().getParent().startActivityForResult(...)
I can handle the result on MainActivity
Thanks again